# Can anyone identify what Chinese mythology creature this is?

Tags: mythical-creatures, chinese

I got this as a gift and I originally thought it was a foo dog but it has both paws on turtles, not on a cub or ball as foo dogs do. It may be a Pi Yao or Pixiu but I'm not so sure.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it has hooves (not paws), scales,  and horns, it is almost certainly a [qilin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qilin) or "Chinese unicorn". I don't know why it is standing on four turtles, except that the turtle and qilin were two of the [sishou](http://www.onmarkproductions.com/html/ssu-ling.shtml) or "four divine creatures", along with the phoenix and dragon.

They could be guarding dragon and phoenix eggs (the red spheres are different sizes) but this is just a guess.

Comment: I dont see the horns facing directly upward....

Comment: OP's statue isn't the most artfully modeled one. Anyway, the qilin is represented in numerous ways; the second link contains qilin carvings almost identical (sans turtles and eggs) to the one in OP.

Comment: True, just pointing it out.

Comment: Horns look like goat's horns.

Comment: It also appears to have scales like a qilin.

Comment: Good point @T.E.D.